# Jquery slide the content up into view from the bottom of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to figure out how I can slide some content upwards (to bring it into view not hide it) whilst also fading in.

I can't seem to find any information I can understand on how to do this, but I know it's possible as I've seen a few website sliders doing it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: [jQuery Animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a fiddle that shows you how to do this.

```
function moveUp(container, object, speed) {
    var speed = 1000 || speed;

    container.css("position", "relative");
    object.css("position", "absolute");
    object.css("top", container.height() + "px");
    object.css("opacity", "0");

    object.animate({
        top: 0,
        opacity: 1
    }, speed);
}

moveUp($("#container"), $("#content"));
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/2HcrN/

Comment: Does it work if you encapsulate the 'moveUp' function call in $(document).ready(function { moveUp.. }); ?